# Отправка http-запроса на C#

Tags: c#

Приветствую!

Подскажите как отправить http-запрос на сайт, и прочитать ответ? Напр. если страница возвращает 200-й код значить все норм, если 404-ю то такой страницы нет...Спасибочки!!!

**UPD:**
вот написал код:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://hashcode.ru/");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Нельзя обработать ответ (404)");
            }
            else if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Страница загружена");
            }

            response.Close();
            Console.Read();
        }
```

в данном варианте пишет "Страница загружена", если урл сменить на http://hashcode.ru/index.aspx, то вылазит исключение, а должно то написать "Нельзя обработать ответ (404)", помогите пожалуйтса!

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском. Берегите свое время. [C# http запрос][1]
[1]:https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23%20http%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=ee920817dbbcffe7&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=656

Comment: если поменять на HttpStatusCode.NotFound все равно тоже самое

Comment: сами попробуйте код вставьте себе :)пишет что сервер вернул 404

Comment: Это не исключение. Это код возврата HTTP, исключение это когда программа выдает ошибку, которую надо либо обработать, либо завершить программу. Так какое исключение вылазит?

Comment: вот запустите код и сами увидите что возвращает! смысл рассказывать на пальцах?

Answer (score 7):

Например, так:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Всё норм.");
}
else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Такой страницы нет.");
}
response.Close();
```

[Полный список кодов.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx)

Comment: получаю исключение

Comment: исключение в студию!

Comment: Пишет сервер вернул 404, и программа останавливается. А если адрес правильный ввести то все норм пишет...

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

При вызове метода GetResponse(), в случае какой-либо ошибки (404, 403 и др.) срабатывает исключение WebException. Необходимо отловить это исключение, в нём есть свойство WebResponse, которое необходимо преобразовать его к HttpWebResponse. В нём уже будет всё необходимое для обработки ошибки - и HTTP код ошибки, и полный заголовок, и веб-страничка, которую передал сервер как страничку соответствующей ошибки.

```
WebRequest webr = WebRequest.Create("http://server/page");
HttpWebResponse resp = null;

try
{
    resp = (HttpWebResponse)webr.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
}
```

Далее обрабатываем как обычно:

```
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet));

string sReadData = sr.ReadToEnd();

switch (resp.StatusCode)
{
    case HttpStatusCode.OK:        //HTTP 200 - всё ОК
        break;
    case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden: //HTTP 403 - доступ запрещён
        break;
    case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:  //HTTP 404 - документ не найден
        break;
    case HttpStatusCode.Moved:     //HTTP 301 - документ перемещён
        break;
    default:                       //другие ошибки
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вот тут наверное у него должно вылезти исключение:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

наверное нужно либо в try{} обрамить, либо попробовать программу не из под компилятора запускать, а на прямую, уже откомпилированную.