# Request/Response через модем

Tags: модемы

У меня есть ноутбук на котором есть сетевая карта. Как я понимаю, благодаря сетевой карте, на модем по WiFi посылается мой запрос, а тот уже в свою очередь посылает запрос на сервер. Так вот где я могу найти у себя на компе конечную точку отправления запросы по WiFi модему?

Comment: Вопрос не до конца понятен, да и ответ на него будет пересказом базового курса по компьютерным сетям. Если интересуют такие вопросы, лучше пройти подобный курс [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLFA0soYGhw&list=PLtPJ9lKvJ4oiNMvYbOzCmWy6cRzYAh9B1), например.

Comment: Вот я например ввожу в браузере адрес. После нажатия ENTER на сервер по этому адресу посылается запрос. Как я могу послать запрос напрямую через модем(без браузеров и подобного софта)?

Comment: Браузер - http клиент, который формирует запросы. Общается напрямую он с операционной системой, которая дальше знает каким образом устанавливать соединения и передавать данные. Такой запрос можно сделать в своей программе на любом языке программирования. [Пример на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95943/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c).